# Uncaught TypeError: theme.palette.common is undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI. I have a container and inside it I have two child components a Box and another container. here is the code:

```
import { Button, Container } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import {Box} from "@mui/systems"
import MovieCard from "./MovieCard";
const MovieList = () => {
 
  return (
   <Container>
      <Box
        sx={(theme) => ({
          mb: theme.spacing(2),
          width: "40vw",
          mr: "auto",
          ml: "auto",
          bgcolor: theme.palette.common.white, // here is the problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        })}
      >
        <Button>Show Movies</Button>
      </Box>
      <Container
        sx={(theme) => ({
          width: "40vw",
          border: "1px solid black",
          borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
          padding: theme.spacing(2),
          bgcolor: theme.palette.common.white, // here the same line of code without problem
        })}
      >
        <MovieCard />
        <MovieCard />
        <MovieCard />
      </Container>
</Container>
)
```

If I add that bgcolor to the box sx prop I get the "Uncaught TypeError: theme.palette.common is undefined" error and everything crashes. under the Box component, I have a container with exactly same bgcolor and same value but get no error. can someone please explain the problem?

Comment: @RyanCogswell yes this is the full copy of my code and also I added the imports

Comment: @RyanCogswell yes exactly that was the problem. but I don't know why that 4 line above that bgcolor line, when I assigned mb:theme.spacing(2) it didn't give me that error if it hadn't access to the theme. anyway, it worked. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import `Box` from `@mui/system` instead of `@mui/material`, then it won't have access to the full default theme provided by `@mui/material` unless you [explicitly provide it](https://codesandbox.io/s/boxsx-material-demo-forked-sjyn6?file=/demo.js) via `ThemeProvider`.

`theme.spacing(2)` still worked because `@mui/system` provides a simple default theme which [includes the spacing function](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.4.1/packages/mui-system/src/createTheme/createTheme.js#L16), but the [default palette](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.4.1/packages/mui-system/src/createTheme/createTheme.js#L23) in @mui/system is nearly empty.